# C# Element not found while trying to open serial port

Tags: c#, bluetooth, windows-10, ioexception

I have strange trouble, when I want to print on printer connected via Bluetooth. When I run my program, I get error message:

> System.IO.IOException: Element not found. *(I hope it's good translate)
>
> v System.IO.Ports.InternalResources.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String str)
>      v System.IO.Ports.SerialStream..ctor(String portName, Int32 baudRate, Parity parity, Int32 dataBits, StopBits stopBits, Int32 readTimeout, Int32 writeTimeout, Handshake handshake, Boolean dtrEnable, Boolean rtsEnable, Boolean discardNull, Byte parityReplace)

The code is:

```
        SerialPort port = new SerialPort();

        port.PortName = listBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
        port.BaudRate = 9600;
        port.Parity = Parity.None;
        port.StopBits = StopBits.One;

        port.DtrEnable = true;
        port.RtsEnable = true;

        if (port.IsOpen)
            port.Close();

        try
        {
            port.Open();
            port.Write("Test.");
            port.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            textBox.Text = ex.ToString();
        }
```

The thing is, when I run this app on Win 8/8.1 it prints OK. When I try it on Windows 10, I got this message. Is there anyone, who can give me any advice? Thanks.

Comment: What's the value for `PortName`? Is it definitely the right COM port for the Bluetooth device? You may have to assign one on Windows 10 (http://www.collideabq.com/2016/04/28/bluetooth-serial-connection-with-windows-10/)

Comment: I think, its the right COM port, because in bluetooth settings is just COM5 and COM6. COM6 doesn't work at all (it's for incoming), COM5 lights up the blue LED on printer... But after that light, there is just error msg.

Comment: Tried Bluetooth Serial Terminal. I can print from this app, but still not from my own app :(